# Using something other than cy.request to seed data in Cypress

Tags: cypress

I'm using Cypress for end-to-end testing. In my `beforeEach`, I'm using an SDK I've been provided to seed data on a server (the SDK sends API calls to the server but does not use `cy.request` inside it). The method on the SDK returns a promise, therefore I figured I could return the promise like so:

```
beforeEach(() => {
  return sdk.createProperty(...);
});
```

My test then does something like this:

```
it('displays a property', () => {
    cy.visit(`/companies/${appTestData.companyId}/properties`);
    ...the rest is commented out currently...
}
```

This actually works as intended, that is, it waits until the server response is returned before running the tests, but I see the following warning in the console when the test actually runs:

```
Cypress Warning: Cypress detected that you returned a promise in a test, but also invoked one or more cy commands inside of that promise...
```

I noticed if I change my `beforeEach` to use `cy.then`, the warning goes away:

```
beforeEach(() => {
  cy.then(() => sdk.createProperty(...));
});
```

It seems a bit unnecessary and was kind of a stab in the dark, so I'd like to know if there's a prescribed way of doing what I need to do. I can't change the SDK I'm using to use `cy.request`, which I assume would also prevent the warning. Thanks.

Comment: See [Waiting for Promises](https://docs.cypress.io/api/utilities/promise.html#Waiting-for-Promises), where you substitute `sdk.createProperty()` for `waitOneSecond()`. Two things differ to your code: `cy.wrap(null).then(...` and a `return` of the promise, which I presume signals completion to the command chain.

Comment: Correction - your syntax is arrow function so you ***are*** already returning the promise.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Probably not what you want to hear, but can I confirm you that using `cy.then(...)` is the most standard way of waiting for a Promise in Cypress I know of.

After reading your question, I have tried to use Cypress [Network Requests](https://docs.cypress.io/guides/guides/network-requests.html#Waiting) features to wait for a `fetch('my/url')` in a `before()`, but it doesn't seem to be detecting the request at all.

Comment: I can't find anything saying otherwise, so I'm rolling with this as the answer. Thanks for responding!